# Generate disjoint star-like subgraphs based on equalities

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Consider this toy example:

```
MERGE (:Obj {desc:'A',id:1})
MERGE (:Obj {desc:'A',id:2})
MERGE (:Obj {desc:'A',id:3})
MERGE (:Obj {desc:'A',id:4})
MERGE (:Obj {desc:'B',id:5})
MERGE (:Obj {desc:'B',id:6})
```

I have 6 different nodes, but there are only two different values for the description (so, only two classes of nodes). Suppose I want to create now a relationship `SAME_AS` through which all nodes having the same description will be *connected*. That is, that I should be able to get from a node *x* to all other nodes having the same description traversing `SAME_AS` relationships.

For the connected subcomponents I would prefer star-like graphs, where for each *category* the node with the smallest `id` acts as prototype to which all other *equivalent* nodes link to. (Another possibility, not as good, would be Hamiltonian paths)

So far, I only came up with this

```
MATCH (o1:Obj), (o2:Obj)
WHERE o1.desc=o2.desc AND o1.id<o2.id
MERGE (o1)<-[:SAME_AS]-(o2)
```

But it builds a clique for each class.

Better *solutions* required using a `MATCH` within a `FOREACH` statement, which isn't allowed in `neo4j`.

I don't even get whether `cypher` is appropriated to do this, or whether I should perform these calculations outside `neo4j` and only afterwards write the info within the DB.

Thanks

Comment: do you think you should change your question? _"I am not even specially interested in a Hamiltonian path, I would even prefer a star-like one"_

Comment: @DaveBennett Done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this

```
// match the objects
MATCH (o1:Obj)
WITH o1.desc AS desc, o1

// put them in ascending order so we can find the smallest
ORDER BY desc,o1.id

// collect them per description
WITH desc, collect(o1) AS objs

// connect 1..n to node 0
UNWIND RANGE(1,size(objs)-1) AS idx
WITH objs[0] AS origin, objs[idx] AS dupe
MERGE (origin)<-[:SAME_AS]-(dupe)
```

Comment: Small question: `ORDER BY o1.desc,o1.id` could also be `ORDER BY desc,o1.id`? you just gave it an alias in the line above.

Comment: oh yeah, that is my bad all the way. i will tidy it up - good catch